# How do I add a typing animation to the text in my UITableViewCell?

Tags: swift, xcode, uitableview, animation, uilabel

I haven't worked with UITableViews before, and so I'm new to the animation effects you can have with UITableViews and UITableViewCells. Though, I'm not deterred. So how would I go about coding a typing animation for when text is being displayed in my UITableViewCell?

I'm creating a text-based story game in Xcode. The premise is simple with how the app essentially runs: the user is presented with a story (story text), and when the user makes a decisions (a choice out of two UIButtons displayed), then a new UITableViewCell is generated beneath the previous cell containing the old story so that we have story progression (and of course new decisions are displayed alongside the new story). The cells and buttons are separate from each other if you have to know.

Anyway, I thought by having the story being typed out in newly generated cells (new cells that are made when the user makes a decision) rather than having the text being displayed immediately in the newly generated cells would be a lot better (because it's cooler). So how do I code the typing animation for my story text in the cells? Would it be better to use an extension or write code within my ViewController? I don't need my buttons being typed out.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

An animation is just a series of property changes over time. A lot of animations can be done automatically given a starting point and an ending point and some animation parameters, like the time it should take. For example, if I want a view to grow from a width of 100 to a width of 200 and for that to take 2 seconds, UIKit can automatically do that for me with a simple call to animate the change. It will figure out all of the in-between states and set them over the time interval.

Unfortunately, for you, your animation does not fall into the kind that can be automatically done. You will have to start a timer to set the text and redraw the cell for each character of the string you want to set.

Here is the basic idea -- you would need to make it fit your code.

```
var amountTypedOut: Int

func typeOutText(text: String) {
    amountTypedOut = 0
    Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1.0, repeats: true) { (timer) in
        if amountTypedOut < text.count {
            // You need to write `updateCellWithTypedText` to 
            // update the cell in your table.
            // Make sure you do this on the main thread
            amountTypedOut += 1
            updateCellWithTypedText(text.prefix(amountTypedOut))
        } else {
            timer.invalidate()
        }
    }                
}
```

Comment: Thank you heaps for responding and giving me an elaborate explanation and code example. I'll give it a crack and see how it goes. I appreciate the help, Lou.